# Ajax data is lost while refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an `user_id` and `comment` field in database.

In my view section there is a comment box and when an user comments and clicks the submit button, I triggered jQuery ajax function and retrieved that id and comment from database and displayed in a `div`.

I get the desired comment and the id in the division but the problem is whenever I refresh the page those data disappears. I used the innerHTML property to assign the ajax value to the div. Is there any way that I can display those data and they do not disappear even after I refresh the page?

Comment: Yes. Fetch the data from the DB when loading the page. It is as simple as that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want data to persist through page reloads you will need to render it on the server. So basically you need to construct the HTML dynamically using some server side language by fetching the existing comments from the database.

Alternatively if you don't use server side language you will need to fetch the comments from the server when the page loads (in the DOM ready event) using an AJAX call.

Comment: thanks..i am currently doing the same as u have told..fetching the comments from server using DOM ready event using AJAX. i just want the fetched data to persist inside the div. It would be a great help if u can give me a solution about this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reflects a poor understanding of what AJAX actually is:

It's an asynchronous method of exchanging data between browser and server after your page has loaded. Hence, your Page is always the same, without all the additions you made "at runtime".

What you could do is implement some logic to reconstruct a specific state from e.g. a session.

I'd discourage you to do that alone, however. It's often pretty clever to also include the essential state information in the URL/href of the page, allowing the user to "bookmark" a specific display. But that of course depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if the button or element you use to trigger the ajax query is inside the form tags. Try putting the button outside of the form tags. My problem was solved this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fetch the data from server side and display for current session,

Way 1: you can use "[Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)" concept

```
    Store Data
     sessionStorage.setItem('record - 1', 'My comments');
     sessionStorage.setItem('record - 2', 'My comments 2');
    
    Retrieve Data
     let comments_1 = sessionStorage.getItem('record - 1');
     let comments_2 = sessionStorage.getItem('record - 2');
```

The data which you store in this session storage will persist even after you reload too

Way 2: Use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) to store the data (not preferred)

Way 3: Make a [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) call from client side on page load to get the comments of current record and display on-fly [Preferred]

Based on your convenience you can choose the way to code :)